# I can't bring Selenium to load the rest of the website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm not really sure how to ask this.. basically i want to click the loadmore button as long as there is one to have the full website. The only thing thats stopping me is that I'm not able to locate the orange load more (mehr anzeigen)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from urllib.request import urlopen
#from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)

# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))

#use keys to get where the button is
html = wd.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(0.5)
html.send_keys(Keys.END)
time.sleep(0.5)
html.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_UP)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "loadNextBtn")))
loadButton=wd.find_element_by_class_name("loadNextBtn")
actions.move_to_element(loadButton)
time.sleep(0.5)
actions.click(loadButton)
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: im new to stack i tried to answer with my code and what didnt work but the message was too long:(

Comment: im very sorry i didnt mean to ignore you but didnt know how to state my problem in a meaningful way without code

Comment: i see i will keep that in mind the next time i ask a question.
sorry for that!

Comment: Well if you even still want to answer me here i will try to state where i am:
im able to get to the div class which "surrounds" the span class with the button and get the cursor there. Problem is the div class is not exactly where the button is so i will have to either move the cursor by a certain amount on the x axis or get access to the content of the span class





<div class="loadNextBtn"><span type="button" class="md-text-button button-orange-white" onclick="loadFollowing();">mehr anzeigen</span></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "loadNextBtn")))
loadButton=wd.find_element_by_class_name("loadNextBtn")
```

Please try this:

```
load_next_btn_xpath = "//div[@class='loadNextBtn']//span"
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, load_next_btn_xpath)))
loadButton=wd.find_element_by_xpath(load_next_btn_xpath)
```

Also you have to know that

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))
```

will not wait for presence of all elements matching the passed locator.
This method returns a list of matching elements found immediately after detecting at least one element matching the passed locator.
So if you really want to wait until all the elements are presented you will have to add `time.sleep()` after that line...

Comment: hey, thanks a lot :) i did in fact just get it myself through xpath so thats definetly the right suggestion. thx for the details regarding time.sleep

Comment: also for some reason action chains didnt work for me, out of bound error . had to use LoadButton.click()

Answer (score 1):

heres the code that worked for me:
notable is that first i had to use xpath. second fullscreen was needed to stop a support chat window from blocking the button
third for some reason action chains didnt workout for me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# Set some Selenium Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

# Webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
# URL
url = 'https://www.techpilot.de/zulieferer-suchen?laserschneiden%202d%20(laserstrahlschneiden)'

# Load URL
wd.get(url)
wd.fullscreen_window()
# Get HTML
soup = BeautifulSoup(wd.page_source, 'html.parser')

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#bodyJSP #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#efficientSearchIframe")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".hideFunctionalScrollbar #CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fancyCompLabel")))

#use keys to get where the button is
html = wd.find_element_by_tag_name('html')

c=2
#range : number of times load button will be pressed 
for i in range(3):
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(1)
    html.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(1)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='resultPane']/div["+str(c)+"]/span")))
    loadButton=wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='resultPane']/div["+str(c)+"]/span")
    loadButton.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    c+=1
```

Comment: Maximizing the screen is a good catch! I didn't see that since I didn't run your code :)

Comment: Actions.move() may not work sometimes, especially when the element is not actually loaded on the page